# Trouble querying SQL Server database via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a web form using a custom login control to access a local SQL Server database. The database contains a table named `Employees` with various info about the employee, however, the relevant columns for my question are `EmployeeID` (primary key), `Username`, and `Password`.

I am trying to query the database using the username and password entered in the login control to retrieve the `EmployeeID`. An exception is thrown when trying `ExecuteScalar()`. The exception states that 'Employees' is an invalid object name, so I suspect my problem is the connection string. I retrieved the connection string by viewing the properties of the database in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, which is where I also created the db. Another guess is that authentication when connecting to the db. I'm not really sure though, so can someone help please?

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Joshua\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\SSDT\\SignProDatabase\\SignProDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
string query = "select EmployeeID from Employees where Username = 'user' and Password = 'pass'";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

try
{
    object test = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
}
catch(Exception err)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + err);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Your connection string is for trusted security. This means it is connecting using the security account given to the web site not the user account you are logged in with.

Comment: What is cmd ? I don't see it declared in the posted code.

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is good.........parameterize your sql queries.  Look for the "don't ever do this" (which is what you are doing in the above) in this article and find the better way to do it.  http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06

Comment: I'm guessing you are not connecting to the correct database or the user account you are connecting with doesn't have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin mentioned in the comments, the account that is running the application will need access to the server and database, as well as select permission on the Employees table.  Also, if the code provided is not just for example then for security reasons you shouldn't be storing the actual passwords in your database and you will want to validate the input to protect against SQL injection attacks.